# Sort photos based on name in powershell

Tags: powershell, photo

I have used Advanced Renamer to rename all my photos by date, so they all have names such as:

2017-Oct-14_8;39_kyd.jpg

Where "8;39" is the time and "kyd" is a string of three random characters to reduce eliminate duplicate names. I would like to write a powershell script to sort them all into folders such as:

C:\Pictures\2017\Oct

Where the first directory would be the year and the second directory would be the month. If a photo does not have date taken metadata, it's name would be:

"--_;_kyd.jpg"

and I would like to sort it into a "MANUAL_SORT" folder located is C:\Pictures. I am trying to use powershell to do this and this is what I have so far:

```
$SourceFolder = 'C:\Pictures\Test'
$DestinationFolder = 'C:\Pictures\Test_Output'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.jpg | ForEach-Object
{
$filename = $_.Name.Substring(0,7);
if ($filename.Substring(0,3) = "--_;")
{
    Move-Item -Path $SourceFolder -Destination "$DestinationFolder\MAUNAL_SORT"
}
else
{
$Year = $filename.Substring(0,3)
$Month = $filename.Substring(5,7)
Move-Item -Path $SourceFolder -Destination $DestinationFolder\$Year\$Month
}
}
```

But I can't figure out how to use the ForEach-Object command to cycle through each picture. Can anyone suggest a method to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- substring of name while retrieving filename, removed that code
- if condition comparison - it should be '-eq'

Also please verify folder exists or not added #TODO

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.jpg | ForEach-Object {
    $filename = $_.Name;

    if ($filename.Substring(0,3) -eq "--_")
    {


        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$DestinationFolder\MAUNAL_SORT\"
    }
    else
    {
    $Year = $filename.Substring(0,3)
    $Month = $filename.Substring(5,7)
    #TODO: test path if directory exists else create it
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName  -Destination $DestinationFolder\$Year\$Month
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! It works! Thanks! I knew my code would be full of bugs, I am pretty new to powershell usage. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using Move-Item incorrectly. Use `$_.FullName` as the argument to the -Path parameter. As written, you're repeatedly trying to move the entire source folder into the destination.

Your string comparison operations are wrong. Use `-eq`.

Your substring calls are getting one too few characters. The parameters are `index` and `count`. Index is zero-based, of course, but count is the actual number of characters you want.

Also, the `$filename` variable is only accomplishing an extra call to Substring(), it's not useful in the rest of the script.

```
gci $SourceFolder -Filter *.jpg | foreach {
  $YYYY = $_.Name.Substring(0,4)
  if ($YYYY -eq '--_;') {
    mv $_.FullName $DestinationFolder\MANUAL_SORT\
  } else {
    $MM = $_.Name.Substring(5,3)
    mv $_.FullName $DestinationFolder\$YYYY\$MM\
  }
}
```

Comment: There are other bugs, like `$Year = $filename.Substring(0,3)` only pulls `201`.

Comment: It works! Yep, I knew my code would be full of problems. Included mostly to convey the concept of what I am trying to do. Thank you for your help!